# JQuery form on submit calling recursively

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, security, jcryption

I am doing encryption for username and password in JavaScript using Jcryption algorithm. and decryption using Java . in that process before encryption process completion in JavaScript form is submitted .In Java I am not getting encrypted username and passwords. and I am getting normal values so I am prevented form submit and written code in the form submit after the encryption process completed I am calling submit event but form submitting multiple times.
give me suggestions is there any way to solve issues .or any alternate way to solve issues.

Thanks In Advance

My Html code

```
    <form name="frm" method="post" action="/xsl-portal/xlogin" onSubmit="" target="_parent"  autocomplete="off"> 
       <input type="text" maxlength="45"  name="eid1" id="eid1" />
       <input type="hidden" maxlength="45" id="eid" name="eid" />
       <input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" />
       <input type="image" src="home-images/button-submit.png" id="submitButton" value="Submit" name="image"  onclick="submitButtonClick();" />

<input type="hidden" value="" name="submit" id="submit"/> 
    </form>
```

> ```
> Javascript code
> ```

```
    var keys='';

    function getKeys() {
        $.jCryption.getKeys("/sakai-login-tool/EncryptionServlet?generateKeypair=true", function(
            receivedKeys) {
            keys = receivedKeys;        

        });
    }
    getKeys();
    var encryptedUser='';
    var encryptedPassword='';
```

/* form submit code*/

```
// $('#submitButton').on('click',function(){
            function submitButtonClick(){ 



            }
        // });

$('form').submit(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
                var user=$('#eid1').val();
                    var password=$('#pw').val();

                    encryptionProcess(user,password).pipe(applyValues).pipe(function(){

                        console.log("eid"+$('#eid').val());
                    console.log("pw"+$('#pw').val());
                    $('form').submit();
                    });
    })

;
    function encryptionProcess(user,password){
        var d= $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.jCryption.encrypt(user, keys, function(encrypted) {
                encryptedUser = encrypted;
                console.log("printing user encryption:"+encryptedUser);
            });
            $.jCryption.encrypt(password, keys, function(encryptedPasswd) {
                encryptedPassword = encryptedPasswd;                    /**
                 * As both userName and password are encrypted now Submit login
                 */
                 console.log("printing password encryption:"+encryptedPassword);
                });
              d.resolve();
        }, 10);
    return d.promise();         
    }
    function applyValues(){
        var d1= $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#eid').val(encryptedUser);
            $('#pw').val(encryptedPassword);
          d1.resolve();
        }, 10);
        return d1.promise();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `$('form').submit();`. Since you are calling the jQuery [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method, it will call the associated submit event handler causing a recursive cycle

Change it to use the dom element's [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) method, which will not result in the invocation of submit event handlers.

```
$('form')[0].submit();
//or e.target.submit();
```

Comment: Hi Arun How are you.I am added your code but i am getting Uncaught type error:Object is not a function

Comment: @sarath make sure that there are no elements with name/id `submit` in your form

Comment: form contained name attribute. i removed name attribute but i am getting same error

Comment: can you share the form's markup.. or check whether any input field in the form has the name/id as submit

Comment: @sarath did you try `e.target.submit()`

Comment: also add a logging statement like `console.log(e.target);console.log(e.target.submit)` before the `e.target.submit()` call

Comment: tried i am getting same error object is not a function

Comment: @sarath what is logged in the browser console

Comment: for first log displaying form and second log displaying hidden submit form <input type="hidden" value="" name="submit" id="submit"/>

Comment: that is the problem... the input element has the name and id as submit

Answer (score 0):

Change your `submit` button to be a normal button.  Listen for the click on this button and within that handler call `$('form').submit();`

The way you are doing at present will result in recursive submits.

Comment: I am used in put type image

Comment: an image would be fine too.  Just listen for a `Click` not a `Submit`

Comment: i am taken button and  calling submit() function in java i am getting normal values

Comment: i tried button click event  but before completion of click event form is submitting so i tried in form submit